# Asp classic on iis7 dns less connection issue

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, dns

I cant get dns less connection to Ms Access db to work here the code.

In the dbconnection.asp file is this

```
Dim MM_IMT_STRING
''MM_IMT_STRING = "dsn=EDA;"
MM_IMT_STRING =("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\essel\Connections\EDA.mdb")
```

and in the default.asp is this

```
<!--#include file="Connections/dbconnection.asp" -->
Dim CHANNEL
Dim CHANNEL_numRows

Set CHANNEL = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
CHANNEL.ActiveConnection = MM_IMT_STRING
```

I have been struggling with this issue for days now, if someone know why its not linking up please tell me thanks.

Comment: when i try a view a file in the browser i get this now "HTTP/1.1 New Application Failed" is something not configured properly or what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your Connection object created?

I'm missing something like

```
Set objConnMDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
objConnMDB.ConnectionString = MM_IMT_STRING
objConnMDB.Open
CHANNEL.ActiveConnection = objConnMDB
' // do your stuff here '
objConnMDB.Close
Set objConnMDB = Nothing
```

Comment: Good, so you have a connection object already.. that's what you need to assign to the ActiveConnection, not the string